# XMLHttpRequest doesn't work asynchronously

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

Here's my JS

```
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open('POST','/some-location',true);
        req.send("A string to be processed server-side");

        var resp = req.responseText;
```

Trouble is, it just doesn't work. Whenever I use `console.log(resp)` to see the response, it's an empty string.

But when I change the second line to `req.open('POST','/some-location',false);`, `resp` is the processed result. I don't want to set async to `false`, though.

Is there a plan Javascript way to see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: it in fact works asynchronously, so try printing the result right after that won't work. You have to use some callback. it's here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/readystatechange

Comment: simple example about this here http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because it is not an AJAX request. You must use AJAX. It is not very complicated and you can find instructions at

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp.